# What is the remainder when $4^{100}$ is divided by 6?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to find the remainder when $4^{96}$ is divided by 6.

SO using the cyclicity method,

Dividing $4^1$ by 6 gives remainder 4.

Dividing $4^2$ by 6 gives remainder 4.

Dividing $4^3$ by 6 gives remainder 4.

Dividing $4^4$ by 6 gives remainder 4.

Dividing $4^5$ by 6 gives remainder 4.

..

..

So by this method we get the answer as `4`.

But when we reduces this to

> > $$ 4^{100} /6 $$  to 
> >     $$ 2^{200} /6 $$

which is equal to

> > $$ 2^{199} /3 $$

Then by using the cyclicity method:

Dividing $2^1$ by 3 gives remainder 2.

Dividing $2^2$ by 3 gives remainder 1.

Dividing $2^3$ by 3 gives remainder 2.

Dividing $2^4$ by 3 gives remainder 1.

Dividing $2^5$ by 3 gives remainder 2.

..

..

So accrding to this ,We get the answer as **2**.

So which one is correct?

And how we are  getting two different answers for the same numbers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first answer is right. The last step of your second argument is incorrect. You could (correctly) argue that $4^{100} \equiv 1$ (mod 3) and $4^{100} \equiv 0$ (mod 2), so that $4^{100} \equiv 4$ (mod 6)

Comment: Geoff : I am not able to get you. I have added a proof of 2nd argument .Can you tell me where i am wrong?

Comment: The error comes in assuming that $2^{200}$ (mod 6) is the same as $2^{199}$ (mod 3). It is true that $2^{200}$ divided by $6$ is the same as $2^{199}$ divide by $3,$ but you are talking about remainders in the question.

Comment: $4 \pmod{6} = 4$ but $2 \pmod{3} = 2$. Clearly the two are not the same.

Comment: But $4^{100}/6 $   is equal to   $2^{200}/6$ .

Comment: and 4/6 = 2/3, but 4 (mod 6) is not equal to 2 (mod 3).

Comment: But in integer division, $2^{200}/6$ is *not* the same as $2^{199}/3$. You can easily see this with lower exponentials: $2^4/6 = 16/6 = 2,\text{ remainder }4$ but $2^3/3 = 8/3 = 3,\text{ remainder }2$.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: You surely meant $\frac{2^{199}-2}{3}$.

Comment: @celtschk: Yes, I did indeed. Thanks. Confusing error in this context. Should have read ``$\frac{2^{200} - 4}{6} = \frac{2(2^{198}-1)}{3}$, which is twice an integer. Hence $2^{200} \equiv 4$ (mod 6)."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first method is correct.  Since $4\times 4 \equiv 4 \mod 6$, you can conclude $4^n \equiv 4 \mod 6$ for $n \ge 1$.

The second method is wrong.  A simple example is that it suggests the remainder when $8$ is divided by $6$ is the same as the remainder when $4$ is divided by $3$.

If you know that $$2^{2n-1} \equiv 2 \mod 3$$ and $$2^{2n} \equiv 1 \mod 3,$$ then modulo $6$ you can conclude  $$2^{2n-1} \equiv 2 \text{ or } 5 \mod 6$$ and $$2^{2n} \equiv 1  \text{ or } 4 \mod 6.$$ You want the latter expression.  You can similarly say that since $2^m \equiv 0 \mod 2$ you can conclude $$2^m \equiv 0 \text{ or } 2 \text{ or } 4 \mod 6.$$ Put those two together and you get  $$2^{2n} \equiv 4 \mod 6$$ which is the first result.